# mongodb - Why is this query not using the index?

Tags: mongodb

I created an index over this field:
ws.eId

so a query like this is pretty fast, which uses a BTree cursor:

db.workout.find({"ws.eId" : "648"})

However this query does not use the indexed field, which uses now a Basic cursor:

db.workout.find({"ws":{"eId" : "648"}})

-Why is this? -How can I make the 2nd query use the indexed field? Or should I just create an index for ws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query searches the field `ws` for an object with exactly that one field with that value.  It can't use an index for that because the object might have more fields than just `eld` and would then be ineligible for the return set.

To speed up this query, create an index on `ws`.